# What is vortex row image system in fluid mechanics?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, vortex, imaging

What is [vortex row image system](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=vortex+row+image+system) in fluid mechanics? I have lot search but I did not find any best answer about this question. Please explain about this topic or give me best link of book or site.

Comment: Please explain me.